# Converting a map of pointers to map of of objects

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, lambda

I have a map which has pointers to objects as keys (values are int). Given this, I want to create a map that is identical to the original map, but I want the keys to be the corresponding objects (aka dereferenced keys)

Here is my code:

```
map<const Point*, int> m1 = createMap();
map<Point,int> temp;
for_each(q.begin(), q.end(), [&temp](pair<const Point*, int> p){temp.insert(make_pair(*(p.first),p.second));});
```

What I'm trying to do is call a lambda that simpley derefrences the keys of the initial map.

The compiler however complains that "/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_function.h|235|error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const Point’ and ‘const Point’)|"

Am I making a foolish mistake somewhere?

Comment: Does your Point struct define a "<" operator? Compiler know how to compare pointers, but it does not know how to compare two user defined struct or class if you do not define an operator for that

Comment: Note: The maps will not be 'identical': (1) The resulting map will likely have a different order. (2) The resulting map may have less elements (There might be two pointers to an identical point)

Comment: Hmm. Is there a way I could avoid the (2) case ?. The big picture is that my algorithm (function) returns the first map. In order to test its output though I need a map of objects (not pointers).

Comment: @Dieter Identical pointers would be assigned just a single element in the map, wouldn' they? If so, both maps will have identical number of elements. Point (1) is nonetheless true.

Comment: @DrD I mean: Pointers pointing to two points (at different addresses), where the point values are identical

Comment: If pointer1=&obj1, pointer2=&obj1 => pointer1=pointer2. Then, when inserting them in a map, the second insertion doesn't happen, as &obj1 is already there.

Comment: @DrD ptr0 = &p0, ptr1 = &p1 where p0 == p1

Comment: haha! you're right :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define *operator<* for your class Point.

A map is an ordered collection of elements. Hence you need to implement a function to order them. By default, that function is *operator<*, but you can specify a different one in the constructor if you want.

Se here, for example:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: Ooops! I forgot that map keys are sorted containers. C++ newbie. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to do that?